# How can I call a function at regular intervals in SDL?

Tags: c++, timer, sdl, intervals

I need to keep track of an interval of time and call a function each time the interval has passed. I've consulted SDL's documentation on `SDL_AddTimer`, but gcc is complaining that I'm doing it wrong.

So, how can I make regular intervals, or how do I use `AddTimer`?

The examples for `AddTimer` in the SDL docs weren't clear to me. gcc has told me that I'm missing arguments in my callback function and that my timer doesn't exist in the scope (but I don't know what to declare). Here's what I've crappily tried:

```
SDL_AddTimer(3000,changeMusic,NULL);
Uint32 changeMusic(Uint32 interval, void *param){...
```

I thought maybe if the time elapsed was divisible by 3 seconds, then the function would run, but this ended up activating at an erratic frequency.

```
if(interval.getTicks()%3000==0){
    changeMusic();
}
```

Or, if a countdown hit zero, reset it and call a function, but I don't know how to make a timer that counts down.

```
//something like this
cdTimer=(3000 to 0)
if(cdTimer==0){
    cdTimer=(3000 to 0);
    changeMusic();
}
```

Comment: Q: What is the gcc error or warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure, from your snippet, that you didn't declare the function before the call to SDL_AddTimer(), and thus the compiler thinks it's the wrong function parameters.

There are two solutions:

1. Move the callback function from the SDL_AddTimer() to somewhere before the timer call.
2. Use a forward declaration to move the function up.

It's also possible that you are trying to use a member function in a class, in which case it would have to be a static member function. Something like this:

```
class Mylene
{
 public:
    ... // other stuff goes here ... 
    static Uint32 ChangeMusic(Uint32 x, void *p)
    {
         Mylene *self = reinterpret_cast<Mylene *>(p);
         self->doChangeMusic();
         return 0;
    }

    ... more stuff here, perhaps ... 
};


Mylene mylene(...);  // Note, must not go out of scope before the ChangeMusic is called. 
// ... stuff ... 
timer_id = SDL_AddTimer(3000, &Mylene::ChangeMusic, &mylene);   // Passing the mylene object... 

... Do other things here for some time ...
```

Comment: Gah. It really was just an order issue. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Excellent. I thought it might be - having done that a few times myself. I do learn, but slowly... ;)